# How to access child's state in React? (React Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What's the best solution to get access to the child's state using react-hooks?

I've tried various approaches. Below the one that I've ended up with.

## Form (Parent)

```javascript
export const Form: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ onFinish, initState }) => {
  const formInputsStateRef = useRef({})

  const handleFinish = () => {
    const params = formInputsStateRef.current
    console.log(params)
    onFinish(params)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Inputs initState={initState} stateRef={formInputsStateRef}  />
      <S.Button onClick={handleFinish}>
        Finish
      </S.Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

## Inputs (Child)

```javascript
export const Inputs: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ initState, stateRef }) => {
  const [pool, setPool] = useState(initState.pool)
  const [solarPanel, setSolarPanel] = useState(initState.solarPanel)

  useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = { pool, solarPanel }
  })

  const handlePoolInput = () => {
    setPool('new pool')
  }

  const handleSolarPanelInput = () => {
    setSolarPanel('new solar panel')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{pool}</h2>
      <S.Button onClick={handlePoolInput}>Change pool</S.Button>
      <h2>{solarPanel}</h2>
      <S.Button onClick={handleSolarPanelInput}>Change solar panel</S.Button>
      <h2>-----</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

It works that way but I don't like the fact that it creates an object on every render.

---

Inputs(Child)

```
useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = { pool, solarPanel }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass pool and solarPanel as the second argument to `useEffect` so that the state is updated to ref only on these values change

```
export const Inputs: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ initState, stateRef }) => {
  const [pool, setPool] = useState(initState.pool)
  const [solarPanel, setSolarPanel] = useState(initState.solarPanel)

  useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = { pool, solarPanel }
  }, [pool, solarPanel])

  const handlePoolInput = () => {
    setPool('new pool')
  }

  const handleSolarPanelInput = () => {
    setSolarPanel('new solar panel')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{pool}</h2>
      <S.Button onClick={handlePoolInput}>Change pool</S.Button>
      <h2>{solarPanel}</h2>
      <S.Button onClick={handleSolarPanelInput}>Change solar panel</S.Button>
      <h2>-----</h2>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However to have a more controlled handle of child values using ref, you can make use of `useImperativeHandle` hook.

**Child**

```
const InputsChild: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ initState, ref }) => {
  const [pool, setPool] = useState(initState.pool)
  const [solarPanel, setSolarPanel] = useState(initState.solarPanel)

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    pool,
    solarPanel
  }), [pool, solarPanel])

  const handlePoolInput = () => {
    setPool('new pool')
  }

  const handleSolarPanelInput = () => {
    setSolarPanel('new solar panel')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{pool}</h2>
      <S.Button onClick={handlePoolInput}>Change pool</S.Button>
      <h2>{solarPanel}</h2>
      <S.Button onClick={handleSolarPanelInput}>Change solar panel</S.Button>
      <h2>-----</h2>
    </div>
  )
}

export const Inputs = forwardRef(InputsChild);
```

**Parent**

```
export const Form: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ onFinish, initState }) => {
  const formInputsStateRef = useRef({})

  const handleFinish = () => {
    const params = formInputsStateRef.current
    console.log(params)
    onFinish(params)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Inputs initState={initState} ref={formInputsStateRef}  />
      <S.Button onClick={handleFinish}>
        Finish
      </S.Button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks the first solution works. The second one with the `useImperativeHandle` unfortunately not.

Comment: Did you use `forwardRef` when exporting Inputs component `export const Inputs = forwarRef(InputsChild);` for the second solution

Comment: Works, small change needed: 

```const InputsChild: FunctionComponent<IProps> = ({ initState }, ref ) => {...}```

What's the advantage of this approach of the first one? What do you mean by the `more controlled handle of child values`?

Comment: By using useImperativeHandle you restrict the parent to access only those methods/values from child which the child wants to expose.

Comment: In your parent, should the render reference `InputsChild` instead of `Inputs`?

Comment: @ecoe, InputsChild is a component passed on to forwardRef hoc and hence the parent will refer to Inputs and not InputsChild

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thanks I missed that line, but what about instead of using refs if the `parent` just passed the `child` a function as a prop that the `child` could then call when it makes a change to `pool`?

Comment: I am getting ```Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?``` on the last approach.

Comment: Nevermind, second option worked with a few modifications. Upvoted!